# MySQL - which query will be faster

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, benchmarking

I have a database (MySQL) that contains information about photos, their ratings (people can vote) and comments.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Photos` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` NVARCHAR(2000),
  `Author` INT,
  `Contest` INT,
  `PhoneModel` NVARCHAR(200),
  `PhotoThumbPath` NVARCHAR(2000),  
  `PhotoPath` NVARCHAR(2000),
  `Date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `State` INT DEFAULT 1,
  FOREIGN KEY (`Author`) REFERENCES `Users`(`ID`), 
  FOREIGN KEY (`Contest`) REFERENCES `Contests`(`ID`), 
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PhotoComments` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Author` INT,
  `Photo` INT,
  `Comment` NVARCHAR(2000),
  `Date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ReplyTo` INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (`Author`) REFERENCES `Users`(`ID`), 
  FOREIGN KEY (`Photo`) REFERENCES `Contests`(`ID`), 
  FOREIGN KEY (`ReplyTo`) REFERENCES `PhotoComments`(`ID`), 
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PhotoComments` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Author` INT,
  `Photo` INT,
  `Comment` NVARCHAR(2000),
  `Date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ReplyTo` INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (`Author`) REFERENCES `Users`(`ID`), 
  FOREIGN KEY (`Photo`) REFERENCES `Contests`(`ID`), 
  FOREIGN KEY (`ReplyTo`) REFERENCES `PhotoComments`(`ID`), 
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now I want to ask database for a certaing photo to give me how many comments it has, how many ratings and what's the average rating.

Which one of those ways will be faster:
query with subqueries 3:

```
SELECT P.PhotoPath, P.Date, P.PhoneModel,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PhotoComments C where C.Photo=P.ID) as CommentsCount,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PhotoRatings R where R.Photo=P.ID) as RatingsCount,
(SELECT COALESCE(AVG(Rating), 0) FROM PhotoRatings R where R.Photo=P.ID) as RatingsAvg 
FROM Photos WHERE P.ID=$photoID
```

or one big query with 2 left joins:

```
SELECT P.PhotoPath, P.Date, P.PhoneModel,
COUNT(DISTINCT C.ID) as CommentsCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT R.ID) as RatingsCount,
COALESCE(AVG(R.Rating), 0) as RatingsAvg
FROM Photos P
LEFT JOIN PhotoComments C ON C.Photo=P.ID
LEFT JOIN PhotoRatings R ON R.Photo=P.ID
WHERE P.ID=$photoID
GROUP BY P.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) on your querys, and compare the result